# SD Card as a Network drive in Wi-Fi Network?

Tags: wi-fi, sd-card, networking

Please help me to emulate my Phone's SD card as a network drive in my Wi-Fi network. I am able to mount it as a Media device which will only help us to play music with Windows Media Player. But I want my SD card as a network drive.

Comment: You are searching for an app that acts as SMB/CIFS server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good application to do that is the [Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmZ1bmt5ZnJlc2guc2FtYmEiXQ..). It shares your sdcard, making it easy to transfer files from/to your phone.

## Settings

After installing the application from Google Play, open it and fill a password by touching the password menu. The default username is **SDCARD** and the default Workgroup is **WORKGROUP**. You can leave it that way or change it in a way that suits you.

[image: Settings Menu 1]

I'd recommend enabling and selecting your WiFi in the **WiFi White List** . That way it only enables Samba sharing when connected to your preferred Network.

[image: Settings Menu 2][image: WiFI White List][image]

That done, you only have to go to your Network Shares and look for a device called **ANDROID**.

## Login

- Name: SDCARD
- pw: (the one you defined earlier)

Open the shared folder and it will ask again for credentials, and you're done.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gX3etC8X1ys) you have a video that completes this information.